# How to get current object on partial colection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following partial:

```
<%= render partial: "shared/cards",
                collection: @products,
                as: :product,
                ga_event_category: 'Redirect #{product.name}'
%>
```

How can I get the product name in this case?
Because I'm using collection I can't have access to the object on every dynamic iteration?

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to pass in a single name for the entire collection?  Wouldn't you want to set each product's event category individually inside the partial?

Comment: including the ga_event_category key in the render method isn't allowed. Not sure what you're trying to do with it. The `product` object is available in the partial, and you can interpolate the string there, inside the partial.

Answer (score 0):

Rails makes the instance object available inside the partial using the name of the partial (without the underscore) as the instance variable.

> When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the collection being rendered via **a variable named after the partial**.

Read this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

In your case, I'd rename the partial as `product`.

`render partial: "shared/product", collection: @products`

Inside that partial you can set the value of `ga_event_category` using the `product` instance from the collection.

If you don't change the name of the partial, the collection instance would be `cards`.

Comment: my question is not about using product instance inside partial. I would like to know if I can use as a reference in the partial call.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

```rb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= render partial: "shared/cards",
             product: product,
             ga_event_category: "Redirect #{product.name}"
  %>
<% end %>
```